# Rails ActiveRecord includes with run-time parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a few models...

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :voter, class_name: 'User'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

In my controller, I have the following code...

```
user = User.find(params[:userId])
games = Game.includes(:manager, :votes)
```

I would like to add an attribute/method `voted_on_by_user` to game that takes a user_id parameter and returns true/false. I'm relatively new to Rails and Ruby in general so I haven't been able to come up with a clean way of accomplishing this. Ideally I'd like to avoid the [N+1 queries problem](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) of just adding something like this on my Game model...

```
def voted_on_by_user(user)
  votes.where(voter: user).exists?
end
```

but I'm not savvy enough with Ruby/Rails to figure out a way to do it with just one database roundtrip. Any suggestions?

**Some things I've tried/researched**

- [Specifying conditions on Eager Loaded Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations)

  - I'm not sure how to specify this or give the includes a different name like `voted_on_by_user`. This doesn't give me what I want...

  `Game.includes(:manager, :votes).includes(:votes).where(votes: {voter: user})`
- [Getting clever with joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations). So maybe something like...

  `Game.includes(:manager, :votes).joins("as voted_on_by_user LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON votes.voter_id = #{userId}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already `include`ing `votes`, you can just count `votes` using non-db operations: `game.votes.select{|vote| vote.user_id == user_id}.present?` does not perform any additional queries if `votes` is preloaded.

If you necessarily want to put the field in the query, you might try to do a `LEFT JOIN` and a `GROUP BY` in a very similar vein to your second idea (though you omitted `game_id` from the joins):

```
Game.includes(:manager, :votes).joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON votes.voter_id = #{userId} AND votes.game_id = games.id").group("games.id").select("games.*, count(votes.id) > 0 as voted_on_by_user")
```

Comment: Nice! That first suggestion works like a charm. I just added a loop on games and tacked on an attr_accessor to the model. The second suggestion was throwing an error though.

Mysql2::Error: ...for the right syntax to use near '*)>0

Also, I tried editing your answer to make the code multi-line but SO wouldn't let me because edits have to be at least 6 chars. If you could do that it might make things clearer for future visitors :)

Comment: Sorry, just edited. Should need to count an actual column, so `count(votes.*)` should have been `count(votes.id)`